# How to draw a text box with shadow borders in LaTex

Tags: boxes

How do I draw a text box with shadow borders in LaTex? 
I have tried the following but it has errors:

```
\fbox{
\begin{minipage}[c]{5in}
   \shadowbox{\large\bf text write here}
\end{minipage}
}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Which error does TeX spill out? Did you use `\usepackage{fancybox}` ? And do you really nead a frame around `\shadowbox`?

Comment: i m not using \usepackage{fancybox}, i m new to latex and i want to draw a simple text-box having a shadow border at its left side. i m not understanding how to code this in latex.

Comment: Try to use my provided answer as a starting point. And change `\bf` to `\textbf{...}` since `\bf` is deprecated syntax

Comment: Other packages: `mdframed` or `tcolorbox`

Answer (score 10):

The main question is: How should the box look like? The box can be drawn with unlimited variations using `tikz`, `mdframed`, `tcolorbox`, etc.

Here are some suggestions with `tcolorbox`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[skins]{tcolorbox}
\begin{document}

\tcbox[enhanced,size=fbox,fontupper=\large\bfseries,drop shadow southwest,
    sharp corners]{(A) text write here}

\begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced,width=5in,center upper,size=fbox,
    fontupper=\large\bfseries,drop shadow southwest,sharp corners]
(B) text write here
\end{tcolorbox}

\tcbox[enhanced,fontupper=\large\bfseries,drop shadow southwest,
    sharp corners]{(C) text write here}

\begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced,width=5in,center upper,
    fontupper=\large\bfseries,drop shadow southwest,sharp corners]
(D) text write here
\end{tcolorbox}

\tcbox[enhanced,fontupper=\large\bfseries,drop fuzzy shadow southwest,
    colframe=red!50!black,colback=yellow!10]{(E) text write here}

\begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced,width=5in,center upper,
    fontupper=\large\bfseries,drop fuzzy shadow southwest,
    colframe=red!50!black,colback=yellow!10]
(F) text write here
\end{tcolorbox}

\tcbox[enhanced,fontupper=\large\bfseries,drop fuzzy shadow southwest,
    boxrule=0.4pt,sharp corners,colframe=yellow!80!black,
    colback=yellow!10]{(G) text write here}

\begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced,width=5in,center upper,
    fontupper=\large\bfseries,drop fuzzy shadow southwest,
    boxrule=0.4pt,sharp corners,colframe=yellow!80!black,colback=yellow!10]
(H) text write here
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Is there an easy way to use these boxes with a paragraph?

Comment: @GlenWheeler Inside the `tcolorbox` examples, you could use paragraphs, but not inside the `tcbox` examples.

Answer (score 3):

With `tikz`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node [copy shadow={fill=blue,shadow xshift=-0.5ex,shadow yshift=-0.5ex},
            fill=blue!20,draw=blue,thick,font=\bfseries] {text write here};
  \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

This is highly customizable as can be seen below:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node [copy shadow={draw=red,fill=red,opacity=0.5,shadow xshift=-0.5ex,
           shadow yshift=-0.5ex},fill=blue!20,draw=blue,thick,font=\bfseries]
            {text write here};
  \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]