# Simple solution to add a shaded image border

Tags: graphics, tcolorbox, border, shadows

I want to make a shaded image border. My current solution is using `\shadowbox`:

```
 \documentclass[12pt]{article}
 \usepackage{tikz}
 \usepackage{fancybox, graphicx}  

 \begin{document}
    \shadowsize=1mm
    \color{blue}
    \shadowbox{\fboxsep=3mm\fcolorbox{white}{white}{\includegraphics[width=12cm,height=8cm,keepaspectratio]{example-image-a}}}
\end{document}
```

So 1) there must be a white border 2) which casts a shadow. But this creates a very "simple", solid shadow: [image]

I would like to achieve a more "blurry effect".

Based on [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/223738/151175) answer I wrote something like this:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[skins]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{fancybox, graphicx}

\begin{document}
  \begin{center}
      \begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced,width=12cm,height=8cm, center upper,
          fontupper=\large\bfseries,drop fuzzy shadow southeast,
          boxrule=0.4pt,sharp corners,colframe=yellow!80!white,colback=white!10]

      \includegraphics[width=12cm,height=7.9cm,keepaspectratio]{example-image-a}
      \end{tcolorbox}
      \end{center}
\end{document}
```

but as you can see, I need this colorbox to scale with my image (which is max 8x12cm, keeping aspect ratio). 
[image]

I saw some overly complicated answers with applying some rules but I really believe there must be a simpler solution.

Besides - can the above solution actually drop shadows to 4 sides of the world, not only `southeast` etc?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`\tcolorbox` is either using the `\linewidth` or the sizes specified with `width` and `height` which may be wrong considering the internal content.

`\tcbox` changes the size according to the inner content and scales appropriately.

I have defined a `\whiteshadowbox` with some options, the centering is done with the `before` and `after` keys.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[skins]{tcolorbox}

\newtcbox{\whiteshadowbox}[1][]{%
  enhanced, 
  center upper,
  fontupper=\large\bfseries,
  drop fuzzy shadow southeast,
  boxrule=0.4pt,
  sharp corners,
  colframe=blue,
  colback=white!10,
  before={\begin{center}},
    after={\end{center}},
  #1%
}

\begin{document}
  \whiteshadowbox{%
    \includegraphics[width=12cm,height=7.9cm,keepaspectratio]{example-image-a}
  }

  \whiteshadowbox[colback=green]{%
    \includegraphics[width=5cm,height=6cm,keepaspectratio]{example-image-a}
  }
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Update with `halo` option**

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[skins]{tcolorbox}

\newtcbox{\whiteshadowbox}[1][]{%
  enhanced, 
  center upper,
  fontupper=\large\bfseries,
  fuzzy halo={0.9mm with gray},
%  drop fuzzy shadow southeast,
  boxrule=0.4pt,
  sharp corners,
  colframe=blue,
  colback=white!10,
  before={\begin{center}},
    after={\end{center}},
  #1%
}

\begin{document}
  \whiteshadowbox{%
    \includegraphics[width=12cm,height=7.9cm,keepaspectratio]{example-image-a}
  }

  \whiteshadowbox[colback=green]{%
    \includegraphics[width=5cm,height=6cm,keepaspectratio]{example-image-a}
  }
\end{document}
```

**With `size=tight` and `boxsep=1cm` settings**

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[skins]{tcolorbox}

\tcbset{
  halobox/.style={
    enhanced,
    center upper,
    fontupper=\large\bfseries,
    size=tight,
    boxsep=1cm,
    fuzzy halo={0.9mm with gray},
    boxrule=0.4pt,
    sharp corners,
    colframe=blue,
    colback=white!10,
    before={\begin{center}},
      after={\end{center}}}
  }

\newtcbox{\whiteshadowbox}[1][]{%
  halobox,
  #1%
}

\begin{document}
  \whiteshadowbox{%
    \includegraphics[width=12cm,height=7.9cm,keepaspectratio]{example-image-a}
  }

  \whiteshadowbox[colback=green]{%
    \includegraphics[width=5cm,height=6cm,keepaspectratio]{example-image-a}
  }
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Instead of `fuzzy shadow` use `fuzzy halo` to get a 'full shadow'

Comment: Thank you. Is there a way to manipulate the size of the box? Let's say that in your latter example I would like the green area to be 1cm wide in each directon?

Comment: @kch:  `\whiteshadowbox[colback=green,boxsep=1cm]{...}` should work

Comment: @kch: Added a third example (without screen shot, however. See the `halobox` style settings.

Answer (score 7):

It's is very simple with the `pstricks` module `pst-blur`:

```
\documentclass[12pt, svgnames]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pst-blur} 
%\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}% to compile with pdflatex --enable-write18 (MiKTeX) or pdflatex --shell-escape (TeXLive, MacTeX)

 \begin{document} 

\begin{pspicture}
 \psframebox[linecolor = RoyalBlue, framesep = 4mm, shadow, blur, shadowcolor = RoyalBlue, shadowsize = 1.5mm ]{%
 \includegraphics[width = 12cm, height = 8cm, keepaspectratio]{example-image-a}}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]